# How to check if the delayed job is actually retrying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have the following method

```
def max_attempts
  3
end
```

But I want to check if Internet is not there, or the third party connection I am establishing is not available. I want delayed job to retry it. I have switched off internet, but I cannot see `Delayed::Job` getting populated.

Comment: Are you trying to check "the third party connection I am establishing is not available or available from job" ?

question not clear , describe what are you trying to process from delayed job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check:

```
Delayed::Job.find(id).attempts
```

`attempts` should show you haw many attempts it tried to do and if it reached the maximum it will stop trying.

Make sure you are not catching the error some where, otherwise the Delayed job will think its success and will be removed from the table.

Comment: If the internet is not there , I cannot see the table getting populated

Comment: why you think DJ should fail when internet is not working ?

Comment: The code I have in the perform method, deals with some third party API which required internet. Can you please correct me if I am wrong, and also show me a way to actually check max_attempts method would work